# How to get the text(which not under any node) from div in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and I am stuck on a problem.

I need to get the text which comes directly from the div.

Example :

```
<div id ="parent_div">
<label>text1</label>
text2
</div>
```

in above HTML I need to get text2 which come directly under the div, but I don't want text1 in output.

So far I have tried

```
document.getElementById("parent_div").textContent
```

and

```
document.getElementById("parent_div").innerText
```

but I got both text1 and text2.

Please help me to get text2 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove all the texts from the other elements:

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("parent_div");
var text = ele.innerText;
for (var i = 0; i < ele.children.length; i++) {
  text = text.replace(ele.children[i].innerText, "");
}
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div id="parent_div">
  <label>text1</label> text2
</div>
```

Comment: Accepting the answer as your code handle the scenario where we have <br> in text

Answer (score 2):

`text1` will always appear, unless you hide it.

To get the sibling text, use:

```
document.getElementById("parent_div").childNodes[2].textContent;
```

Check the `childNodes` property to see where I get the number `2`.

Comment: I don't know what will be the childNode's index. HTML page is dynamic.

Comment: What "child" will you be getting? You can always iterate through the `childNodes`

Answer (score 1):

you could do it like this

```js
var cloned = document.getElementById('parent_div').cloneNode(true);

Array.from(cloned.children).forEach(function(child) {
  cloned.removeChild(child);
})

var text2 = cloned.innerText;
```

```html
<div id ="parent_div">
<label>text1</label>
text2
</div>
```

Comment: It removed DIV's rest of the child from UI

Answer (score 1):

Filter by `nodeType`, you can get all the children from the element, then you can filter by what you need, you're looking for the `nodeType 3` that represent all the text elements inside the div, the label is just ignored because is `nodeType 1`, you can learn more about this here in [the documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp), there's my example working. I filtered all the next line texts, to give you only the one that you need.

```js
let el = document.getElementById("parent_div"),
    child = el.firstChild,
    texts = [];

while (child) {
    if (child.nodeType == 3) {
        texts.push(child.data);
    }
    child = child.nextSibling;
}
const text = texts.join("").replace(/\n/ig, '');
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div id="parent_div">
<label>text1</label>
text2
</div>
```

Here you can now by more specific with what want you want

Comment: It is working for me, but what if Text has <br> in between.
example :


<div id="parent_div">

<label>text1</label>

text2<br>is<br>what we need

</div>

Comment: Oh, in that case I think is still a nodeType 3 because the br don't create element blocks, but I think that for the same reason the "is" will not have space or next line properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following (covers scenarios where there can be multiple text nodes scattered around many child nodes)

```js
var response = ""; // result

document.getElementById("parent_div").childNodes.forEach(function(node){
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) { // check for text nodes
      response += node.textContent.trim(); // adding text nodes
  }
});

console.log(response); // trim to get rid of leading and trailing spaces
```

```html
<div id ="parent_div">
<label>text1</label>
text2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to use `jquery` in such cases. Just because it makes life easy for me :)

And this is the way you can do that

```js
var allOfThat = $("#parent_div")
    .contents()
    .filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() !== "";
})[0].nodeValue;
console.log(allOfThat)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="parent_div">
<label>text1</label>
text2
</div>
```

Comment: I am kind of restricted to use javascript.